# UITableViewCell Contents Are Lost When Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `Parser` object that contains 15 items from the internet (articles).

I am trying to load this items in my `TableView`. My problem is that I have 8 items visible at start (4 inch retina simulator) but when it starts scrolling, almost all my contents are lost and I cannot see the rest of the 7 items. Not sure what I am doing wrong, this is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    parser = [[Parser alloc] init];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[parser items] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ArticleCell"];
    Article *article = [parser items][indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = article.title;
    cell.date.text = article.date;

    return cell;
}
```

Edit:

This is what it shows when scrolling, if I log the data before returning the cell inside `cellRowAtIndexPath`:

```
2013-09-29 13:37:05.341 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 0 . Title: Cagliari-Inter, tutte le curiosità
 ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:05.343 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 1 . Title: Cerrone "Oggi abbiamo vinto da squadra"
 ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:05.344 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 2 . Title: Le immagini del 10° "Memorial Prisco"
 ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:05.345 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 3 . Title: Primavera, Udinese-Inter 0-1
 ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:05.345 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 4 . Title: Tutte le immagini della vigilia di Cagliari-Inter
 ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:05.346 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 5 . Title: Udinese-Inter Primavera, 0-0 a fine primo tempo
 ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:05.347 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 6 . Title: Mazzarri "Rischio buccia di banana in un momento di euforia"
 ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:05.348 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 7 . Title: Inter Campus in Bosnia Erzegovina: passi avanti per i progetti a Sarajevo e Domanovici
 ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:11.053 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 8 . Title: (null) ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:28.181 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 9 . Title: (null) ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:29.499 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 10 . Title: (null) ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:29.591 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 11 . Title: (null) ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:35.642 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 1 . Title: (null) ; date: (null) .
2013-09-29 13:37:35.767 Inter[3685:a0b] Article for index: 0 . Title: (null) ; date: (null) .
```

Edit:

Complete code [here](http://pastebin.com/WAuqRdsG).

Comment: do you initialize title and date in your custom cell? or you just connect them from storyboard?

Comment: No, I just connect them from the storyboard

Comment: Its strange that when I scroll, all my elements from items array becomes nil.

Comment: Well, the TableViewController behaves as it should, in that case. The items array is the problem. Is there any other place you are working with items array? Another thread? Are you using ARC?

Comment: No, I don't use ARC and I use it only in my tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: This happens usually when dequeueing cells, you need to use same "unique" id, otherwise the table gets conflicted, try my answer below.

Comment: Can you please add `NSLog(@"Article for index: %d %d . Title: %@ ; date: %@ .", indexPath.column, indexPath.row, article.title, article.date)` before your `return cell` in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Tell us is there any problems.

Comment: See my edit. Also there was no column property for indexpath. (ignore that date is null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the property from (nonatomic, weak)

```
NSMutableString *title; 
NSMutableString *date;
```

to (nonatomic, strong) should solve your problem.

Comment: Showing the source code for Parser would definitely help then.

Comment: Then you may need to change: 
 (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableString *title;
 (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableString *date;

to (nonatomic, strong)

Answer (score 1):

```
 -(void) ViewDidLoad {
  [super ViewDidLoad];
    parser = [Parser alloc] init];
```

You Reallocated  and reinitialised parser, is there any part of the code that you are reloading data?  If not your data store will be empty.

Comment: Hmm, I am not reloading anywhere. I'm new to IOS so can you give me some details

Comment: If data is already inside as I suspect it is, just take out the alloc] init[ statement. if not you need to look for the code that loads it  (is this an XML parser]  …. execute it and then [self.tableView reload data];    this will load whatever you have in parser to the table view.

Comment: Well, my parser parses some xml content and stores the content in a NSMutableArray. in the viewCOntroller if I remove the initialization, my table view will be empty. So I don't quite understand where to reload the data ?

Comment: I am not familiar with your Parser Class if it is anything like TBXML or NSXMLParser - Your data source should be the NSMutableArray …. your tableview delegate methods should reflect this  …. numberofRowsinSection    and cellforrowatindexpath should use the array instead of the parser.

Comment: Yes, I use NSXMLParser using the 3 delegates: didStartElement, didEndElement, foundCharacters. So what your saying is to copy the items from the parser array to a local array inside viewcontroller ?

Comment: Is the NSMutableArray being created in this view controller or the parent class?  If it is in the Parent Class just create an NSMutableArray  property in this view controller and do something like this:      parent -   NewVC *vc = [NewVC alloc] init];      vc.array =  self.array;   [self.navigationCOntroller pushviewcontroller:vc];   return;

Comment: Yes create an @property to contain the parser output and do [tableview reloaddata]; every time the parser adds data;

Comment: I have to go now, ail be back in a few hours

Comment: The thing is, all of the items are added first, and then this data is laoded into the tableview, after that there is no adding of new data in the array. So yhis doesn't change anymore. I made a property like you said, but just copied the data from the Parser array to my viewcontroller array: self.items = parser.items; But doesn't change anything.

Comment: @vBx Paulo's answer makes sense. Probably it's something wrong with your `parser = [[Parser alloc] init];` in `viewDidLoad`. Just for testing purposes, can you comment out that line? What will happen?

Comment: @vBx Have you implemented any of `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` methods in your viewController? If yes, are you changing your `parser` there somehow?

Comment: No, I don't have them implemented. The only place I use the array is inside viewDidLoad. ALso the items inside the array are added only at the beginning, thats it. But when scrolling, the items becomes nil inside the array.

Comment: @vBx Sorry, I can't imagine where the problem is. The only thing that we know, is that *something* happens with your parser, so it starts to return nil objects. If you still want to get help with this, I suggest you to upload your full viewController's and parser's `.h` and `.m` files to something like `pastebin.org` and add that links to your answer so people can see the situation in general. If there is no very secret commercial information, of course.

Comment: @vBx, sorry, I meant 'add that links to your question'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38272/discussion-between-alexandr-paliy-and-vbx)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

1. Please check, if your tableView's `delegate` and `dataSource` are set up correctly. I haven't seen that in your code.
2. Please check, what cell class is registered to your table view. I mean, you need to use tableView's `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` somewhere.

Anyway, I'm used to work with GUI without IB or storyboards (so, I'm doing everything programmatically), so it's possible that you don't need to do that.

Good luck.

Comment: I guess this is done, but I don't quite understand, when one cell goes off the screen when scrolling the item from my array becomes nil.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue before. the cause of my problem is that my view controller get released after I scroll my table view, can you please check if you have same cause?

Comment: Being new to IOS I don't know how to check this, can you explain ?

Comment: try add a - (void)dealloc { NSLog(@"Oops, my view controller is released");
}       to your view controller and see if the this method get called?

Comment: It doesn't get released.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * MyIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
    ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: MyIdentifier];
    Article *article = [parser items][indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = article.title;
    cell.date.text = article.date;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Same problem, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the identifier used should be static string

So declare an identifier which is statisc and assign it

```
static NSString *cellId = @"cellIdentifier";    
ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellId];
```

Also make sure the storyboard cell has the same identifier value.ie here 'cellIdentifier'

Comment: @vBx sure `[parser items]` contains 15 items always?

Comment: Yes, but after I scroll, all of the items becomes nil

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Isn't cellForRowAtIndexPath creating the cells ?

Comment: no i meant the custom cell class u defined, ArticleCell to be precise include its code also to the qn,These info are not engh to get an accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

Check what happens with [[parser items] count] when you scroll. My guess is that it decreases which decrease the row count in your table.

I may be wrong here because I don't know what's Parser (probably your custom class?) but in case if it is used to parse HTTP response, perhaps item count decreases when the parsing has been done?

To check parser item count, add the following to your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

NSLog(@"Parser item count: %d", parser.items.count);

Comment: It is always 15, but they become nil after scrolling.

Comment: Could you put the source code of Parser in your question? Also it would help if you provided parts of code where you add items to parser.